# Maven check style as a part of the build

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

Is there a possibility to somehow force maven to fail the build if there are some `checkstyle` errors? Now I have to run `site` goal to generate `javadocs` and `checkstyle` reports. I want to make it on `install` goal and if checkstyle has some error I need build to fail. Is this possible to achieve?

Now I have my `checkstyle` in reporting block of maven:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>src/test/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Did you look here? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to bind `checkstyle:check` to a Maven lifecycle phase (e.g. validate ) and set `failOnViolation` to true.

Something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>checkstyle</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You don't have to specify either `phase` or `failOnViolation` because they're set to `validate` and `true` by default.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis - did you use both a `code style` and `check style` ?

Comment: @Jonathan checkstyle actually defaults to the verify phase, not validate

Comment: @Noel Yep, not sure why I wrote that. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: The docs (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html) include tag linkXref. But that's flagged by my IntelliJ as "not allowed here". Anyone know why?

Comment: @JWoodchuck - I found those docs to be incorrect, the nested configuration settings within the executions phase doesn't get picked up correctly. 

In my case I was using the google_checks.xml to test out the plugin, however, when I ran the plugin it picked up the default sun_checks instead. Moving the configuration settings to outside the executions was the only way I could get it to pick up the correct file.

Also, IntelliJ now picks up linkXRef, as it wasn't picking it up before - plugin runs as expected with mvn checkstyle:checkstyle (prefer this instead of mvn site for my purposes)

Answer (score 5):

It might have been some time since the question was asked, but this wasn't working for me.

For anyone else that might be having the same issue as me, with the build succeeding despite a multitude of issues, I fixed it by lowering the `violationSeverity` property from its default `error` to `warning` in the plugin's `configuration` block.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it has been a long time since this was asked, I did run into another problem:

`JavadocMethod: Unable to get class information for @throws tag 'X'.`

I solved this by changing the phase from "validate" to "test" so that checkstyle runs after the compile phase.