# Enforcing Code Style in Maven

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

How can I enforce Code Style checks at Maven build-time?

In particular, I'd like to configure both Maven build to use both of these:

- CheckStyle (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/checkstyle.xml)
- Code Style (https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml)

How can I configure my Maven build to fail on a Code Style violation?

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your plugin in the pom.xml, you should be able to set the failOnViolation.

[Maven check style as a part of the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180765/maven-check-style-as-a-part-of-the-build)

**Edit:**

Ah I see... That I know of, [Google Code Style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/intellij-java-google-style.xml) plugin doesn't exist for Maven. I guess I would consider writing your own maven plugin that would do something similar to the checkstyle plugin.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugins.html
and 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/source-repository.html

**Edit 2:**

I guess another option would be to find a way to convert your IntelliJ Codestyle xml into a checkstyle xml and then use the maven-checkstyle-plugin to fail based on those rules.

Comment: But I'm interested in failure on **code style** violations, not checkstyle.

Comment: What do you mean by `That I know of, such a plugin doesn't exist for Maven`? Checkstyle or what ?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a Maven plugin for the Google Code Style stuff that was linked to in the question

Comment: @jmcmahon- regarding Edit 2, could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @KevinMeredith - The two XML formats are similar in that they both accomplish the same task but for different tools. You could 1) write a program that does the conversion from one to the other or 2) look through each check manually and create the checkstyle XML by hand - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html

Comment: I realise this post is quite old, but I wrote a maven plugin using the google formatter at https://github.com/talios/googleformatter-maven-plugin - there's also several other plugins available now ( for Gradle as well ).

Answer (score -1):

We can use the [spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main) project for that. It has plugins for Maven, Gradle, and Sbt-based projects. By default, it uses the Google style format, but it allows customizations.

#### Maven execution

- The `check` goal verifies the current format.
- The `apply` goal applies the changes in the files to be compliant with the current style.

See it in action:

```bash
user@machine repo % mvn spotless:check
[ERROR]  > The following files had format violations:
[ERROR]  src\main\java\com\diffplug\gradle\spotless\FormatExtension.java
[ERROR]    -\t\t····if·(targets.length·==·0)·{
[ERROR]    +\t\tif·(targets.length·==·0)·{
[ERROR]  Run 'mvn spotless:apply' to fix these violations.
user@machine repo % mvn spotless:apply
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
user@machine repo % mvn spotless:check
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

#### Maven sample configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spotless-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <java>
            <includes>
                <include>src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                <include>src/test/java/**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
            <googleJavaFormat/>
            <removeUnusedImports />
            <endWithNewline />
        </java>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The latest `spotless-maven-plugin.version` is available [here](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.diffplug.spotless/spotless-maven-plugin/versions).